# Extracting attachment from email received on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mime, restlet, email-attachments

I want to extract an attachment from mail received in my GAE java app. The attachment will be an image file: JPG, PNG, GIF, etc. I am using Restlet framework in my GAE project. So I extract MimeMessage from Restlet's representation object. But I can't figure out how to extract the image file which came as attachment with the mail.

Below is the code I am using to extract MimeMessage:-

```
@Post 
public Representation addPoints(Representation entity) {
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, entity.getStream());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/449220/java/java/Getting-Multiple-Attachments-MIMEMessage